# How to migrate from Jenkins-core version 1.580.3 to 2.X

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, noclassdeffounderror

I have a jenkins plugin created with version 1.580.3 which is made to a hpi file and uploaded to jenkins.Now that I need to migrate to jenkins 2.X version I was not able to do that.Currently am using jenkins-core ,jenkins-war,jenkins-test-harness set to 1.580.3 .Now when I migrate to version 2.X I was able to correct my unit tests but my integration tests are failing saying null pointer exception .no class definition found error in JenkinsRule.class and FreeStylePrject.class when version is set to 2.0.

No links could save me.CAn someone guide me here?
Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

"No class definition found error" is most probably due to a missing plugin or an incompatible one with your 2.x version. Check in the [update center](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/plugins/) (Manage Jenkins > Manage Plugins) on your Jenkins server if a compatible version of your 1.580.3 plugin is available.

When we are doing Jenkins upgrade, we always make a backup. Then we update the war file, update all compatible plugins and restore the backup if the upgrade is unsuccessful.

Comment: Thanx for the response.What am using is currently a maven project.So I change the jenkins version there,run all the tests and if is successful,I will create a hpi file of this and deploy it in jenkins.So I cannot directly go to manage plugin .Is there any way around for this?